# Extract multiple filenames from multiple paths into multiple strings

Tags: c#, string, file, path

I have a string:

> C:\Users\O&S-IT\Desktop\NetSparkle (4).txt | C:\Users\O&S-IT\Desktop\NetSparkle (5).txt | C:\Users\O&S-IT\Desktop\NetSparkle (6).txt | C:\Users\O&S-IT\Desktop\NetSparkle (1).txt | C:\Users\O&S-IT\Desktop\NetSparkle (2).txt | C:\Users\O&S-IT\Desktop\NetSparkle (3).txt

I want to be able to extract the 6 filenames from the string without their respective paths into 6 new stings such as:

> "NetSparkle (4).txt"
>   "NetSparkle (5).txt"
>   "NetSparkle (6).txt"
>   "NetSparkle (1).txt"
>   "NetSparkle (2).txt"
>   "NetSparkle (3).txt"

The deliminator character is always "|".  The filenames will always be different as will the paths.  The actual number of paths and filenames in the string could be different as well.  Sometimes there could be 3 paths/filenames in the string, othertimes there could be as many as 15+.

How would I do this in C# 3.5+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var fileNames = myString.Split('|').Select(s => Path.GetFileName(s));
```

Comment: This one kills the blank at the end: var filenames = stringToExtract.Split(new[] { " | " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(item => Path.GetFileName(item));

Comment: If I try to do a: Console.WriteLine("'" + fileNames[0] + "'"); with your method, I get this error:  Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>.  How do I use the fileNames output with your method.  Also does your method have the trailing space problem of the first answer on here?

Comment: You can add a `.ToList()` in order to get LINQ to evaluate the expression immediately.

Answer (score 3):

```
var fileNames = input.Split('|')
                     .Select( x => Path.GetFileName(x))
                     .ToList();
```

Or shorter:

```
var fileNames = input.Split('|')
                     .Select(Path.GetFileName)
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: I am getting a trailing space using your method except for the very last file name.  Example:  'NetSparkle (4).txt '   There is a space after the "t" in txt and the "'".

Comment: @fraXis: That must be in your data then - you can fix it using `Trim()`, i.e. `.Select( x => Path.GetFileName(x).Trim())`

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick two-step process.

**Step 1:** Use `string.Split(char)` to get an array of strings. In your case, something along the lines of `string[] files = filelist.Split('|');`

**Step 2:** For each string in the array, chop off everything up to the last slash. Example `files[i] = files[i].Substring(files[i].LastIndexOf('/') + 1);`

I believe you need to `+1` to exclude the last slash. If it cuts your file names short, though, just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion for you:

```
        var stringToExtract = @"C:\Users\O&S-IT\Desktop\NetSparkle (4).txt | C:\Users\O&S-IT\Desktop\NetSparkle (5).txt | C:\Users\O&S-IT\Desktop\NetSparkle (6).txt | C:\Users\O&S-IT\Desktop\NetSparkle (1).txt | C:\Users\O&S-IT\Desktop\NetSparkle (2).txt | C:\Users\O&S-IT\Desktop\NetSparkle (3).txt";

        var fullpaths = stringToExtract.Split(new string[] { " | " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        foreach (var fullpath in fullpaths)
        {
            var filename = Path.GetFileName(fullpath);
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

[String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) will do the trick.

Comment: Not quite... still need the file name portion of the path.